# nodejs jugglingdb belongsTo and hasMany relations with existing db objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, jugglingdb

jugglingdb exposes two functions to create relational dbs:
belongsTo
and
hasMany

i now aks myself how i might use this in daily development.

belongsTo and hasMany are adding functions to the objects,
but as it seems there is no way to create relations between existing objects?

see:
http://compoundjs.com/juggling.html#hasMany
for an example.

i would like to not create the object but instead create linkages between existing objects,
how will that work?

maybe i am just misinterpreting the functions?

have fun

jascha

ps:
would be great if someone with 1500+ rep could create the jugglingdb tag and add it to this question? i really cant say if its relevant enough though.

Answer (score 3):

When you, i.e. want to add articles for an existing author, you can do it like the following:

```
User.find(uid, function(err, user) {
        var article = user.articles.build({articleName : 'Article Foo'});
        article.save();
});
```

That will automatically create a foreign key for user inside the new created article.

Comment: yeah, this part i figured out easily,

but how can i add an existing article to an existing user?

is there something like 
    user.articles.add({_id: idOfExistingArticle)
?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry that I didn't get that. I always do it the other way round, and set the belongsTo from the Article, with the setter function: "existingArticle.mainUser(existingUser);".

Comment: thats pretty nice :)
to be honest i switched back to a pure mongoose install, but if you want to incorporate this into your answer i will accept it :)